# calling locally declared function

Tags: common-lisp

Here's a piece of code from *Land of Lisp* (p 138 or here: http://landoflisp.com/wumpus.lisp):

```
(defun get-connected (node edge-list)
 (let ((visited nil))
    (labels ((traverse (node)
                (unless (member node visited)
                  (push node visited)
                  (mapc (lambda (edge)
                          (traverse (cdr edge)))
                        (direct-edges node edge-list)))))
      (traverse node))
   visited))
```

As a newbie, I'm wondering if the **(traverse node)** of line 9 is where this "locally" defined function finally gets called in the "wrapper" function **get-connected**. That is, when **get-connected** is called, it then "constructs" **traverse** (lines 3 - 8), then calls/uses it on line 9. Also, the local variable **visited** seems to be packed with **push** commands by **traverse**, then left on the back doorstep of the **let** block, I'm guessing, as a "return value?" Of course this must be some manner of return value, "live" and available for the calling function; otherwise, this whole **get-connected** function is moot!

To me, a Lisp/functional newbie, this all seems bizarre. Is this one of those closure beasts I've been hearing about? If so/not, what am I gaining by such a strangely constructed function? I understand what it does -- it starts with a graph vertex and traverses as many edges, remembering vertices, as it can -- but (besides the nice recursion) is this typical Lisp/functional strategy?

BTW, here's an example of an **edge-list**:

```
*test-edges* = ((2 . 8) (8 . 2) (4 . 5) (5 . 4) (6 . 2) (2 . 6) (3 . 10) (10 . 3) (7 . 5) 
(5 . 7) (7 . 10) (10 . 7) (4 . 5) (5 . 4) (9 . 3) (3 . 9) (3 . 5) (5 . 3)
(3 . 1) (1 . 3) (5 . 8) (8 . 5) (8 . 9) (9 . 8) (5 . 2) (2 . 5) (1 . 2)
(2 . 1))
```

and **node** is just one of these numbers, here an integer between 1 and 10. And here's some output:

```
CL-USER> (get-connected 1 *test-edges*)
(9 6 2 8 4 5 7 10 3 1)
```

Comment: ermmm.... what is the question?

Comment: Lisp typical strategy isn't typically functional. The code above hardly qualifies as functional too. `mapc` is the function that is used for side-effect only. The code works by destructively modifying `visited` variable. Which isn't a bad thing, and is rather typical of Common Lisp, just not really functional.

Answer (score 2):

Let's improve the indentation:

```
(defun get-connected (node edge-list)
  (let ((visited nil))
    (labels ((traverse (node)
               (unless (member node visited)
                 (push node visited)
                 (mapc (lambda (edge)
                         (traverse (cdr edge)))
                       (direct-edges node edge-list)))))
      (traverse node))
    visited))
```

The function is not strangely constructed. It's basically a function which sets up some variables, defines a local self-recursive function and then calls the local function once.

What about *closures*? A closure is a function object with an environment. The only place where we construct a function object is in the `MAPC` form  with lambda. Otherwise no function objects are created and passed/returned. The function object, the first argument, passed to `MAPC` is a closure.

We can also write it as two global functions. What is the advantage of the local function approach:

- the local function name is not globally known. Since we only use it locally, there is no real need to make it global.
- we don't need to pass all information to the local function. It has access to the surrounding variables.
- we can have a shared lexical variable which is used to collect the result

We could write it as two global functions. It might look like this:

Now traverse is a global function and we need to extend the parameter list for the list of edges and the list of visited nodes (so far). We also need to construct a return value: the visited nodes.

```
(defun traverse (node edge-list visited)
  (if (member node visited)
      visited
    (progn
      (mapc (lambda (edge)
              (setf visited (traverse (cdr edge) edge-list (cons node visited))))
            (direct-edges node edge-list))
      (cons node (remove node visited)))))
```

A typical pattern you see in functional programming is then also replace the MAPC by some form of recursion.

Now this is our new global function:

```
(defun get-connected-1 (node edge-list)
  (traverse node edge-list nil))
```

It passes the variables and adds an empty list of visited nodes.

Back to the original function:

```
(defun get-connected (node edge-list)
  (let ((visited nil))    ; a shared local variable
    (labels ((traverse (node)    ; a local self-recursive function
               (unless (member node visited)
                 (push node visited)   ; update the shared local variable
                 (mapc (lambda (edge)  ; loop over the direct edges
                         (traverse (cdr edge)))  ; traverse the connected
                       (direct-edges node edge-list)))))
      (traverse node))  ; call the local function from get-connected
    visited))           ; get-connected returns this as the return value
```

What's not so good about above local traverse function? It can cause a stack overflow on certain larger graphs. One would need to rewrite it into a tail-recursive variant.

We also can get rid of the local function and manage the list of visited and not-yet-visited nodes ourselves:

```
(defun get-connected-2 (start-node edge-list)
  (let ((visited nil)
        (nodes-to-visit (list start-node)))
    (loop for node = (pop nodes-to-visit)
          while node do
          (unless (member node visited)
            (push node visited)
            (loop for (nil . to) in (direct-edges node edge-list)
                  do (pushnew to nodes-to-visit))))
    visited))
```